# List / folder of all GTK icons and their names

Tags: icons, gtk3

I am working on a GUI. I use the gi module in Python. I want to add some icons to my GUI but I couldn't find a list of all icons with their corresponding names.
Where can I find such a list? Is there a specific folder in my os where I can view them all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GTK icons are found in `/usr/share/icons`. You can retrieve them with

```
find /usr/share/icons -type f -name '*.png' -o -name '*.svg' -o -name '*.xpm'
```

Pixmap icons can be found in `/usr/share/pixmaps`,

```
find /usr/share/pixmaps -type f
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. I found gtk3-icon-viewer which is what I looked for.

Answer (score 6):

You can set a widget to have a certain icon using the `icon-name` property with admitted values the ones you find inside [`gtk3-icon-browser`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-icon-browser.html) (ex-`gtk3-icon-viewer`):

[image: icon-name property: gtk3-icon-browser selection]

Some widgets which support other properties (like `label` for `Gtk.Button` or `stock` for Gtk.Image, now deprecated) accept as values the ones you find inside [glade](https://glade.gnome.org/) menus instead.

[image: label property: glade icon selection]

Comment: `gtk3-icon-browser` in Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: Note: gtk3-icon-browser is part of the gtk-3-examples package, so you install it using ```sudo apt install gtk-3-examples```